# Can't run docker container with fastapi and connect it to a mlflow registry container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, mlflow

I'm trying to create a MlFlow development environment based on fastapi, postgres, minio and of course mlflow.

I've got the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mlflow_postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres_db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=demo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=demo1234
      - POSTGRES_DB=mlflow_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  mlflow:
    build:
      context: ./mlflow-docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: mlflow
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - mlflow_postgres
    environment:
      - MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://minio:9000
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=demo
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=demo1234
    entrypoint: bash -c "mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql+psycopg2://demo:demo1234@mlflow_postgres:5432/mlflow_db --default-artifact-root s3://mlflow/ --host 0.0.0.0"
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    command: server /data --console-address ':9001' --address ':9000'
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=demo
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=demo1234
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  minio_data:
```

This docker compose file succesfuly create the 3 container with no problem, the minio container, postgres container and mlflow container, i can access them trough the localhost with no problem.

However, I also have a Python script that creates a FatAPI app that spins up a docker container with a random port based on a docker image that load a defined model in the MlFlow registry, the specific command that causes the error is (before this i have created a Mlfflow model and already staged it in production succesfully):

```
port = random.randint(8000,8500)
container = docker_client.containers.run(
        "serve:latest", #docker image
        ports={'8000/tcp':port}, 
        environment={ 
            'model': 'elastic_net',
            'tracking_uri': 'http://localhost:5000',
            'MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL': 'http://localhost:9000',
            'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': 'demo',
            'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY': 'demo1234'
        },
        detach=True
    )
```

It creates the docker container with the random port succesfully but within some seconds I get the container exited with the following error:

> raise MlflowException(f"API request to {url} failed with exception
> {e}") mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to
> http://localhost:5000/api/2.0/mlflow/registered-models/get-latest-versions
> failed with exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000):
> Max retries exceeded with url:
> /api/2.0/mlflow/registered-models/get-latest-versions (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7fbf6e5934f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused'))

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the docker network, i can see that when i run docker compose file that it automatically generate a network in my case called 'mlflowv2_default' but i have tried to put all the docker services in the same network and the one from the docker run in the same network aswell but still got the same error, any guesses?

A you can see in the docker run command it is based on a docker image 'serve:latest', here is the script for that image:

```
import os
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

from fastapi import FastAPI

import mlflow



class Model:
    
    def __init__(self, model_name='elastic_net', stage='Production'): 
        mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://localhost:5000/")
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.stage = stage
        self.model = None
        self.ready = False
        
    def load(self):
        mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://localhost:5000/")
        print(f'Loading {self.model_name} with stage {self.stage}...')
        self.model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(
            model_uri=f'models:/{self.model_name}/{self.stage}'
        )
        
        print(f'Model {self.model_name} loaded succesfully with stage {self.stage}...')
        self.ready = True
        
app = FastAPI()
wrapper = Model()
wrapper.load()

@app.get("/ready")
def ready():
    return{"ready": wrapper.ready}

@app.get("/predict/{item}")
def read_item(item: str):
    prediction = wrapper.model.predict([item])
    return {"prediction": prediction}

t1 = Thread(target=wrapper.load)
t1.start()
```

This script basically checks if the model has been succefully loaded and returns true/false and if it's true, get the prediction.

and this is the dockerfile:

```
# 
FROM python:3.9

# 
WORKDIR /app

# 
COPY requirements.txt .

# 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# 
COPY . .

# 
CMD ["uvicorn", "model_serve:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Any help is very well received!